# java mongodb update specific with array

Tags: java, mongodb, sql-update

I have the following doc stored in MongoDB:

```
{ 
  "id" : "5101",
  "contractId" : "001",
  "dueId" : [{"id":"001"},{"id":"002"}],
  "overdueAmount" : "",
  "amount" : "",
  "customerContact" : "Humus"
}
```

and I want to update to follow data:

```
{ 
  "id" : "5101",
  "contractId" : "001",
  "dueId" : [{"id":"001"},{"id":"002"},{"id":"003"}],
  "overdueAmount" : "200",
  "amount" : "100",
  "customerContact" : "Bim"
}
```

you can see `dueId` is updated(insert a element) and `amount`, `overdueAmount`, `customerContact` are also updated.

How can I use mongodb use update?

Comment: i want update mongodb by only one update statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator you can add new items into the array and [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator you can update other fields.

The query should be like :

```
db.collection.update({"id":"5101"},{$push:{"dueId" : {"id" : "003"}}, $set : {"overdueAmount":"200", "amount" : "100", "customerContact" : "Bim"}})
```

By using Java driver :

```
DBCollection coll = ...

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("id", "5101");

DBObject pushObj = new BasicDBObject("dueId", new BasicDBObject("id", "003"));

DBObject setObj = new BasicDBObject();
setObj.put("overdueAmount", "200");
setObj.put("amount", "100");
setObj.put("customerContact", "Bim");

DBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
updateObj.put("$push", pushObj);
updateObj.put("$set", setObj);

coll.update(query, updateObj);
```

Comment: but how can i use this in java？